# Embed GDB or LLDB inside C++ program and Launch Debugger from the code

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, lldb

Is there a way to statically compile a C++ binary that embeds gbd or lldb, so that the debugger can be launched from within the code?

Essentially, I'd like to be able to spawn the debugger from the code without having to run the code from the debugger.

The best analogy is pasting `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace` in python code to start a debugger at that line of code.

Comment: https://lldb.llvm.org/resources/architecture.html#api tells that there is a C++ API, thus it is definitely possible to embed LLDB into your binary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compile in GDB or LLDB for this to work: you can invoke external binary on yourself:

```
if (some_condition_that_requires_debugging) {
  char cmd[100];
  sprintf(cmd, "/usr/bin/gdb -p %d", getpid());
  // invoke debugger on itself
  system(cmd);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.